# Open outlook meeting scheduled in php

Tags: php, html, outlook

I am trying to make my PHP application to open the Outlook meeting window with some pre-populated fields.

I need it to be as a button to call the Outlook appointment window.
I am able to open a new email window, but I want it to be opened in appointment window at the first place.

[image: Outlook appointment window]

Is there any way to achieve this or do I absolutely have to open the appointment window first and then invite people into a meeting?

Answer (score 0):

The following sample code programmatically creates an appointment, sets various properties, and sends the appointment to request a meeting. `CreateAppt uses the` CreateItem` method to create an AppointmentItem object. It sets the MeetingStatus property of the AppointmentItem to olMeeting to indicate the appointment as a meeting request, and sets a required attendee, an optional attendee, and a meeting location as a resource. The example then displays and sends the appointment item.

```
Sub CreateAppt() 
 Dim myItem As Object 
 Dim myRequiredAttendee, myOptionalAttendee, myResourceAttendee As Outlook.Recipient 
 
 Set myItem = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem) 
 myItem.MeetingStatus = olMeeting 
 myItem.Subject = "Strategy Meeting" 
 myItem.Location = "Conf Rm" 
 myItem.Start = #9/24/2020 1:30:00 PM# 
 myItem.Duration = 90 
 Set myRequiredAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev") 
 myRequiredAttendee.Type = olRequired 
 Set myOptionalAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Kevin Kennedy") 
 myOptionalAttendee.Type = olOptional 
 Set myResourceAttendee = myItem.Recipients.Add("Conf Rm All Stars") 
 myResourceAttendee.Type = olResource 
 myItem.Display 
 myItem.Send 
End Sub
```

Comment: The Outlook object model is common for all programming languages.